# Mapping multiple categories that overlap, but cannot get layer to appear on top consistently ArcMap 10.5

Tags: unique-value

I am trying to map overlapping practices using unique values in ArcMap 10.5. I have a practice for planting and practice for site prep. Planting is a solid fill blue but for some reason the prep practice that is set to crosshatch 10% is only appearing on 1/5 of the polygons that it should. I am a novice so I will attach a picture if someone can help. The area with blue should all be showing cross-hatch. I tried adjusting the advanced symbol levels, but that just got rid of all of the crosshatch. I am not sure exactly how the symbol levels work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would verify that you actually have an overlap of those two categories. Try creating a separate layer with a definition query on it just for the hashed category and prove that there is indeed overlap.

Comment: I figured it out. The overlapping layer was copied from the other so it is indeed an overlap. I did have to define the symbol levels to get it, but my order the first time was wrong.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the order of the symbol levels.

[image]